# Eigenvalues of a block-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, block-matrices

Let $K$ be a positive integer and for each $j=1,\dots,K$ let $A_j\in\mathbb{R}^{p_j\times p_j}$ be symmetric matrices, where $p_j$ is a positive integer. Suppose that each $A_j$ has smallest eigenvalue greater than some universal constant $\eta>0$. Consider the matrix
\begin{equation}
\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & 0 &\cdots&0 \\
0 & A_2 & \cdots&0 \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
0&0&\cdots&A_k
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I am deducing from a past exam question that the smallest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ will also be greater than the constant $\eta$, but I am not sure how to show this - advice would be greatly appreciated.

In a similar vein: I have also deduced this supposed property which I believe to be true but I'm not sure how to show. Say a symmetric matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$ has minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_0>0$. Is it true that $$\inf_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p: \beta\neq0}\frac{\beta^TX\beta}{\|\beta\|_2^2} = \lambda_0,$$ and if so how do I show this?

Comment: If $\Sigma (v_1,...,v_K) = (\lambda_1 v_1,...., \lambda_K v_K)$ you must have $\lambda_k \ge \eta$.

Comment: If the matric is symmetric, it is diagonalisable and you can conclude the latter accordingly.

Comment: Forgive me as my understanding of eigenvalues/eigenvectors is quite incomplete, but why does this equation have implications on the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$?

Comment: Suppose $\Sigma (v_1,...,v_K) = \lambda (v_1,...,v_K) $. Then $A_k v_k = \lambda v_k$. So for each $k$,  either $v_k = 0$ or $A v_k = \lambda v_k$ (and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A_k$). So, either $v=0$ or $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of one of the blocks and so $\lambda \ge \eta$.

Comment: Great, thanks very much!

Comment: Apologies - could you possibly also elaborate on your diagonalisability comment? I can't seem to proceed still for the second claim.

Comment: Prove it for a diagonal $\Sigma$ first and then use a suitable basis of eigenvectors to express $\Sigma$ as a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, since the Matrix $\sum$ is in block diagonal form, the determinant and as such the determinant for calculating the characteristical polynomial, can be calculated by multiplying the determinants of the blocks:
$$ det(\sum)=det(A_1) \cdot det(A_2) \cdot \ldots $$
This is analog for the calculation of the characteristical polynomial and implies that the roots of the characteristical polynomial of $\sum$ is equal to the combination of the roots of the characteristical polynomials of the Matrices $A_i$, $i \in \{1,2, \ldots , k\}$.

Note that the roots of the characteristical polynomial of a matrix correspond to it's Eigenvalues.

As a result we get
$$Eigenvalues(\sum)=Eigenvalues(A_1) \cup \ldots \cup Eigenvalues(A_k)$$